# Acessing BlueStacks' application (WhatsApp) database

Tags: whatsapp, bluestacks

I am trying to get a dump of my contacts' user names, statuses and last seen data.

Since WhatsApp doesn't have an API, I installed it on BlueStacks and am trying to take a snapshot of the database where these details might be stored.

I have a couple of problems:

1. Can't find the database. Where does BlueStacks store its Application data? More specifically, where can I find the WhatsApp user data?
2. If this is not a feasible way to go about it, is there another way to programmatically extract the data I am looking for?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This does not exactly answer my question, but so far, this is the most that I have been able to get.

1. WhatsApp stores a backup of all conversations in the SD Card. It can be accessed by doing the following:

   1. Install a File Manager such as Astro File Manager, on BlueStacks
   2. Navigate to `sdcard/WhatsApp/Databases/`
   3. The message history backups are stored here. Click down on the file `msgstore.db.crypt`, select Copy from the options that come up. Navigate to `/sdcard/bstfolder/bstSharedFolder/` and paste the file.
   4. This file can now be accessed on the PC by navigating to `C:/ProgramData/BlueStacks/UserData/SharedFolder`.
2. Now the messages can be accessed by decrypting the databases ([this link](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1583021) tells you how)
3. The generated HTML contains a table of users (no user names in my case though - but maybe because I hadn't saved the contacts with a name on the emulator), their statuses (though in my case, even when some contacts had statuses, it did not show up), last message times and message histories.

I still haven't been able to find a way to programmatically get last seen timestamps or statuses. :(

Answer (score 0):

My answer maybe not as you wish. But I found something at my place.

I can get the chatting history in txt file. Like what you did for the message backup, but instead of backup all the messages, now just backup for 1 friend chatting message. Then it will store in `sdcard/WhatsApp/Shared/`

Comment: My method does not require one to manually back up the chats. As far as I remember, that is, since this was ages ago!